# django ckeditor upload not working in production

Tags: django, nginx, ckeditor

[image] [image]

django settings:

```
CKEDITOR_BROWSE_SHOW_DIRS = True
CKEDITOR_RESTRICT_BY_USER = True
CKEDITOR_RESTRICT_BY_DATE = False
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "attachments")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'), )

STATIC_URL = f"{FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME}/backend/static/"
MEDIA_URL = f"{FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME}/backend/attachments/"
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/filebrowser/', site.urls),
    path("grappelli/", include("grappelli.urls")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("api/", include(api_urlpatterns)),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                      document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
                      show_indexes=settings.DEBUG)

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                      document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT,
                      show_indexes=settings.DEBUG)

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar

    urlpatterns = [
        path("__debug__/", include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + urlpatterns
```

nginx:

```
  location /project_name/ {
    set $service project_name;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://$service;
    client_max_body_size 16m;
  }
```

In dev all works, upload and browse, but in prod with not (AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/project_name/ckeditor/upload). I try add alias/root to nginx config, change ckeditor path to re_path(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')) and still nothing( Not only upload, browse too not working

For example filebrowse works, but not ckeditor. I dont know a reason why.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add in projects apache settings in service.conf -> WSGIScriptAliasMatch ckeditor alias:

```
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/${SERVICE}/((admin|api|grappelli|ckeditor)/.*)$ /${SERVICE}/backend/${PROJECT}/wsgi.py/$1
```

Now works.